# Ubuntu 22.04 adapts to rk3568

Tags: 22.04, gpu

I tried to port Ubuntu 22.04 to Rockchip rk3568. Ubuntu can run normally, but there is a problem with desktop running. The picture is not smooth. I not sure if x11 whether to use GPU. I installed ubuntu-desktop, use gdm3.

Results of `dmesg`:

[image: this is dmesg display]

Comment: ...and what is the question?